# databinding to datagridview with conditions

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, data-binding, datagridview

I have an application that gets its data from an sql database. I can load my dataset with data and bind it to a Datagridview easy enough. My problem comes when I only need part of the Data. Then I would like to bind only the rows where column(n) = value. Is this possible? I can get by using a different table in my dataset for each different situation, but that could potentially get to be a lot of tables. I haven't been able to find anything online yet, but will keep looking.

For those that need a clarification, The user may need to view data from the same table in the database multiple different ways in different forms at the same time.

```
 DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    With DataGridView1
        .AutoGenerateColumns = False
        datcol.DataPropertyName = "Date"
        Acccol.DataPropertyName = "Account"
        Namcol.DataPropertyName = "Name"
        Descol.DataPropertyName = "Description"
        amtcol.DataPropertyName = "Amount"
        ID.DataPropertyName = "ID"
        .Columns(4).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c"
        .DataSource = MyDataset.Tables("ExpenseData")
    End With
```

This is how I load my main datagridview that shows everything. Now lets say i have a different form that I need to load only the rows where "Name" = "John Doe". Is the correct way to do another call to the database and load another table in the dataset? Or can i filter the current table when I load it?

Comment: Are you really need to load all datatables at once. If you show one table - then you can load from database only table you need

Comment: Please read [ask]...It's really unclear what you want.Please edit your question in order to clarify your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Populate your `DataTable` and bind it to a `BindingSource` and then bind that to the grid. When you want to filter the data, set the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource`, e.g.

```
myBindingSource.Filter = "SomeColumn = " & someValue
```